# Azure Rest API Get More Information about Subscriptions, Resource Groups and Resources

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

Using this [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get#subscription) I can get more detailed information about a Subscription, but is there a way to find CreationDate, CreatedBy, and a list of users who has access to it?

Also the same for Resource Groups and Resources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find all those information - When (EventTimeStamp), who (Caller) and subscription Id) from [ActivityLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activity-logs) REST API

You should filter on operation [Microsoft.Management/register/action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftmanagement) as it represents creation of new subscription

With subscription ID in hand you can use [List role assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-rest) to find who has access to it.

In the same activity log you may find same information as above for resource group and any other resource. creation  of resource group operation: [Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftresources)